# First request timeout in microservices architecture. (IIS 10)

Tags: iis, architecture, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi, ocelot

The company i'm working is implementing (kinda) a microservices architecture. it's half implemented because it has no containers, no orchestrator and they are experimenting because they don't know really how to correctly set everything up. everything is running on top of Internet Information Services 10. all microservices are Restful APIs using .NET CORE 6 and NET CORE 6 Ocelot gateways.

`Any restful Consumer -> Ocelot Gateway -> .NET CORE 6 Microservice`

having that said. i'm in a constant fight with infrastructure & architecture areas because all microservices and gateways goes to hibernate or they kinda shutdown in order to save server resources. I know this behaviour is intended to work like this. the thing is..

The first request to microservices ALWAYS timeouts. so... do you have any recomendations as developer?, are there some techniques i could use to troubleshoot that timeout?

Comment: Enable FRT to see how time is spent in IIS pipeline, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing That can get you started.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.